# Field update based on text field value?

Tags: field-update

I have a custom field(partner type)which is of field type-text and whenever the field value is "sh" in it,I want to update a custom field named "House number" with the value  of a standard field "billing street"..How can I achieve this?

Comment: did you tried with before insert, before update trigger? I can provide the sample code for that.

Comment: Yes,but is there any way to do it using workflows?

Comment: yes. you can use Process builder to achieve the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [CONTAINS](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000004749&language=en_US) function as part a workflow rule or process builder.

Bsed on your requirement, you want a workflow rule that will update a custom field called House number when the value in the billing street field contains 'sh'

The formula is as follows: `CONTAINS('sh',Partner_Custom_Field)`

The formula return type should be a checkbox so it will return true or false and based on that the workflow will trigger.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Nope its not working,because the custom field(House Number) is of type text and the value of the standard field(Billing street) is of type Address???Sorry that I have forgot to mention that

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: -No,Value in the partner type custom field should be "sh" only then, the billing street value should be updated  on the House number field.

Comment: Ok, just replace billing street in the function above with the partner field and when you create the action for the workflow you will attach to the house number field the billing street.